# How are Void points recovered?

Tags: l5r, l5r-5e

I am playing a game of the newest version (5th edition) of the *Legend of the Five Rings* RPG. However, I can't find rules in the book regarding how to recover Void points.

In older editions, it usually required a meditation roll or a tea ceremony roll (which now is a level 2 Shuji) or just plain rest.

Or are you supposed to not recover it as usual any more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Void points are described on p. 36 of the L5R 5e *Core Rulebook*, including a character's starting number and maximum number of Void points, as well as ways to spend and gain Void points.

The book lists the following ways to gain Void points:

> Void points are gained through facing adversity, for without struggle,
> there can be no triumph. Characters can gain Void points in a number
> of ways, most of them representing moments in which the character
> faces adversity and is galvanized to succeed by it. A few common
> instances include:
>
> - After failing a check on which one of their adversities was resolved
>   (see **Resolving Advantages and Disadvantages**, on page 24).
> - Once per scene, after one of their anxieties caused their strife to
>   rise (see **Resolving Advantages and Disadvantages**, on page 24).
> - After choosing to be affected by a complication that the GM (or the
>   controlling player) introduced into the scene (see page 39).
> - After the GM conceals the TN of a check from the players (see **When
>   to Reveal or Conceal the TN**, on page 297).

This is not necessarily a comprehensive list - other specific abilities may also grant additional ways to gain Void points.